# Сombinations without repetitions defined recursively

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, combinations

Suppose we have a set of $\left\lbrace 0,1,2,\cdots,n-1\right\rbrace$, and we want to recursively generate combinations without repetitions of $n$ by $k$ elements.

Let $T(i,j)$ be the $j^{th}$ smallest element of the $i^{th}$ combination in lexicographic order, so the $i^{th}$ combination in the list is $\{T(i,1),T(i,2),\dots,T(i,k)\}$. This procedure computes $T(i,j)$:

[image]

It works pretty nice. But my question is why and how exactly does it works?

To check how the pattern works, one may use this PARI prog:

```
n=6
k=3
a=vector(binomial(n,k),i,vector(k,j,0))
for(j=1,k,a[1][j]=j-1)
for(i=2,binomial(n,k),for(j=1,k,a[i][j]=if(j==k,if(a[i-1][j]==n-k+j-1,a[i][j-1]+1,a[i-1][j]+1),if(a[i-1][j+1]==n-k+j,if(a[i-1][j]==n-k+j-1,a[i][j-1]+1,a[i-1][j]+1),a[i-1][j]))))
for(i=1,binomial(n,k),print(a[i]))
```

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly $T(i,j)$ is doing? Maybe fully work out $T(2,3)$, or something suitable? I cannot understand how that tree gives a subset of $\{0,\dots,n-1\}$.

Comment: @MikeEarnest, thank you for comment! Just try to write a prog and see how it works. For example, for $n=4$ and $k=3$ we have $T(2,3)=3$, because $[T(2,1),T(2,2),T(2,3)]$ is exactly $[0,1,3]$ and that is second combination without repetition in lexicographic order.

Comment: @MikeEarnest, especially for you (or someone else), I already wrote a PARI prog.

Comment: OK, I see now. In the future, it is best if you describe things in words. All confusion would be eliminated if you included a sentence "T(i, j) is the j^th smallest element of the i^th subset in lexicographic order" in your question. This is part of giving context.

Comment: @MikeEarnest, thank you for editing! Do you have any ideas why it works?

Comment: I pretty much get how it works, but I'm still thinking about how to write it up in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\prev}{S_{\text{prev}}}\newcommand\next{S_\text{next}}$
In what follows, I will denote
$$
\begin{align}
\prev &= \{T(i-1,1),T(i-1,2),\dots,T(i-1,k)\}\\
\next &= \{T(i,1),T(i,2),\dots,T(i,k)\}
\end{align}
$$
So, $\next$ comes right after $\prev$ in the lexicographic list of all subsets, and the given algorithm is all about computing $\next$ using $\prev$.

The key idea is this:

> To get from $\prev$ to $\next$, there will be exactly one element $x\in \prev$ which is increased, and replaced with $x+1$ in $\next$. The chosen $x$ is the largest number for which $x< n-1$ and $x+1\notin \prev$.
>
> Suppose there are $r$ elements in $\prev$ greater than $x$; these will replaced with $x+2,x+3,\dots,x+r+1$ in $\next$. Everything less than $x$ will be unchanged in $\next$.

I leave it to you that this rule correctly computes $\next$ from $\prev$. The idea is that you need to increase some element, and since lex ordering counts smaller elements as more significant, you should increase the largest $x$ possible. Everything larger than $x$ can be decreased, so must be.

The other important observation is

> For all $1\le j\le k$, we have $T(i-1,j)=n-k+j-1$ if and only if every number greater than $T(i-1,j)$ is also present in $\prev$. This implies $T(i-1,j+1)=n-k+j$, and $T(i-1,j+2)=n-k+j+1$, etc.

This is just because $n-k+j-1$ is the largest value that $T(i-1,j)$ can assume, since the $k-j$ numbers above $T(i-1,j)$ in $\prev$  need to fit in the range $\{T(i-1,j)+1,\dots,n-1\}$.

Now, let us explain the decision tree case by case.

> If $j=k$ and $T(i-1, j)=n-k+j-1$, then output $T(i,j)=T(i,j-1)+1$.

This means the biggest element of $\prev$ is equal to $n-1$. It cannot be increased, so it will be decreased to be part of a consecutive block with $x+1$, meaning it is one more then the previous element of $\next$, so $T(i,j-1)+1$.

> If $j=k$ and $T(i-1, j)\neq n-k+j-1$, then output $T(i,j)=T(i-1,j)+1$.

This means the biggest element of $\prev$ is less than $n-1$, so it can be increased. This element will be our $x$, and we replace it by $x+1$. Hence, output $T(i-1,j)+1$.

> If $j<k$ and $T(i-1,j+1)=n-k+j$ and $T(i-1,j)=n-k+j-1$, output $T(i,j)=T(i,j-1)+1$.

Here, both $T(i-1,j+1)$ and $T(i-1,j)$ are as big as they can be, part of a consecutive block in $\prev$ ending at $n-1$. This means $T(i-1,j)$ cannot be increased, and it is above $x$, so it will be decreased to the block with $x+1$, hence it is one more then the next smallest element in $\next$.

> If $j<k$ and $T(i-1,j+1)=n-k+j$ and $T(i-1,j)\neq n-k+j-1$, output $T(i,j)=T(i,j-1)+1$.

Since $T(i-1,j)$ is not the biggest it can be, it is a candidate to be $x$, the increased element. Since the next biggest element, $T(i-1,j+1)$, is equal to its largest possible value, there are no bigger candidates, so $T(i-1,j)$ will be $x$, and get increased.

> If $j<k$ and $T(i-1,j+1)\neq n-k+j$, then output $T(i,j)=T(i-1,j)$.

Since the element above $T(i-1,j)$ is not its biggest value, the number $x$ which gets increased will be somewhere above $T(i-1,j)$. All the action happens above, so $T(i-1,j)$ is unchanged from $\prev$ to $\next$.